# $K^{-} + p \rightarrow ...$ most likely outcome?

Tags: particle-physics

I'm supposed to find the most likely outcome for are negative kaon - proton collision. Is there any way to "calculate" this without resorting to measured values (PDG -particle data group)?

Comment: You are asking why the elastic channel $K^-p$ beats $\bar K^0 n,  \pi \Lambda, \eta \Sigma, \pi \Sigma$ ... etc? Beyond Clebsches and masses of exchanged mesons, I can't think of anything... This is medium energy hadronics...

Comment: Is it safe to assume that elastic forward scattering,  $Kp\to Kp$, is not what you mean? This is the limiting interaction at large impact parameters, where a normal person might complain that "the two beams missed each other, of course nothing happened." But "they missed each other" is the dominant interaction in bright beams (or thin targets) as well.